# How do I get multiple substrings in a large string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I've got a large `string`. It has multiple substrings in it like this:

```
pin=1234&
pin=827373&
pin=110&
```

What is the most efficient way to pull out every number between the `pin=` and the `&` symbol and store it in an array, starting from the beginning of the string to the end?

Comment: Regex - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: q1 )is it a single string or string array? q2) is each string is delimited by any character?

Comment: large single string with a lot of html junk in it. it has multiple pin=xxxx& within it.

Comment: Is this query string of some url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pins = Regex.Matches(html, @"pin=([0-9]*)");
var pinArray = (from Match pin in pins select Convert.ToInt32(pin.Groups[1].Value)).ToArray();
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the * most * efficient on the earth, but you can split by `pin=` or `&`. Using the simple `String` methods would be the way to go... splits, for's + indexOf.

But It would require a increasing complex (if`s, successive splits) depending of the struct and complexity of your large string.

I'd still using RegEx for reliability and simplicity:

Filter string for what really matters: `pin=\d+`

Then extract the value: RegEx(`\d`), or better, `value.Replace("pin=", "").Replace("&", "")`

<del>I can't tell more without knowing the struct of your large string.</del>

I've seen now in comments that your large string has HTML content. I would take RegEx approach. I believe it wouldn't be the bottle neck performance issue, even for large strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract multiple pattern matches with `RegEx`:

```
string pattern = @"pin=(\d+)&";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```